# can u send code how to publish dot net contract in pact flow andverify at provider side code

Tags: .net-core, pact, pactflow

I want a little help . I have less experience with automation. Can you send code on how to publish a contract in pact flow? and how to verify the provider-side code. really need very much .send code or reply this message so any one can help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a complete end to end example .NET project here that includes publishing and verifying: https://docs.pactflow.io/docs/examples/

If you are not familiar with coding you should consider pairing with a developer.
Pact is designed as a unit testing tool and requires deep familiarity with the code base being tested.